# How to create an application Independent notification server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io

i have created an notification server, which is application specific, now am preparing an application independent server to send notification to the clients using that application for synchronizing purpose, am not asking code and all, will you give me suggestion on this.
What is the basic need for an development of application independent component?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to create a message queue (pub-sub) that different applications can connect to easily.

If your app isn't that big you can create a TCP server and send information to everybody connected. If you need to scale your app you can use something like Redis, ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ etc.

You can checkout my Twitter Steam application to see how I achieve that:

- app: https://github.com/alessioalex/Presentations/tree/master/WebUp4/applications
- TCP Server implementation: https://github.com/alessioalex/Presentations/blob/master/WebUp4/applications/twitter-streaming/tweetBroadcaster.coffee